# bash loop iterates only once with remote tar

Tags: bash, ssh, tar

I have a script that is a one time run to copy all of our SSLs over to a sandbox server.  The script took me 15 mins to build, and it works perfectly, for a single iteration!  It's the `tar` or `ssh` command that is causing the script to exit, but I can't figure out why, since the script is working flawless, with no exit codes:

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql --login-path=main-data -Ne "SELECT user_file FROM table" | while read user_file; do

echo "$user_file | /var/www/liveSites/websites/$user_file/ssl"

mkdir -p /var/www/liveSites/websites/$user_file
chmod -R a+w /var/www/liveSites/websites/$user_file

rm -rf /var/www/liveSites/websites/$user_file/ssl

sshpass -p SUPERSECRET ssh user@8.8.8.8 tar -zcvf - /var/www/liveSites/websites/$user_file/ssl > /var/www/liveSites/websites/$user_file/ssl.tgz --absolute-names

tar -zxvf /var/www/liveSites/websites/$user_file/ssl.tgz --absolute-names

chmod -R a+w /var/www/liveSites/websites/$user_file/ssl

rm /var/www/liveSites/websites/$user_file/ssl.tgz

done
```

Why when remote tar-ing a directory is my script working, exiting after first iteration without error?

The last line of the loop `rm ...`  runs, so I know it's not "breaking" before that.

Comment: You're missing the ending `"` on the MySQL query.

Comment: TLDR; Add the `-n` option to `ssh`.

Comment: The missing quote was a typo in attempt to obfuscate ..  Let me try the `-n` option

Comment: I know that the quote was a copying error, because the script wouldn't even run that way.

Comment: I never had a reason to use `-n` to prevent reading from stdin --  Thank you that works .. If you answer I'll gladly accept.

Comment: The question is already closed as a duplicate of a question with the answer in it.